# Stop few screen landscape orientation in Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, screen-orientation, uiinterfaceorientation

I am using SwiftUI and Swift in my application. Few screens are expected to support both landscape or portrait orientation.

In Swift, i am using below code to support landscape and portrait orientation

```
    UIDevice.current.setValue(NSNumber(value: orientation), forKey: "orientation")
    UINavigationController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

But i don't know how to do landscape orientation in SwiftUI.

Comment: I did not see anything related in SwiftUI, so do as you did using UIKit - it is still there and alive.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code to control the orientation in swiftui using swift code